# How to get the inactive user in active directory using Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, server

How to get the inactive user in Active Directory with time stamp using Powershell for Windows 2012 server?

Comment: Questions that do not illustrate any effort at are off-topic here. Would you do a thorough search for this first?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example to get you started (not tested but should work in 2012):

```
$DaysInactive = 30 
$time = (Get-Date).Adddays(-($DaysInactive))
Get-ADUser -Filter {LastLogonTimeStamp -lt $time -and enabled -eq $true} -Properties LastLogonTimeStamp | 
select Name, @{l='LastLogonTimestamp'; E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogonTimestamp)}} | sort name
```

This script will get all accounts that have not had the `lastlogontimestamp` attribute updated in 30 days.

Comment: Please note that depending on your definition of "inactive" lastlogontimestamp may or may not be a good idea as it can be off by up to [2 weeks](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/04/15/the-lastlogontimestamp-attribute-what-it-was-designed-for-and-how-it-works/) in a default environment.

Comment: It is important to note that the intended purpose of the lastLogontimeStamp attribute to help identify inactive computer and user accounts.